# GIT Diff with blame or source SHA

Tags: git, git-diff, winmerge, blame, git-blame

We feel we do a good job or reviewing each commit before merging in to master.

However when we are ready for a new software release I often take one more review.  I diff the last production release against the current production candidate.

As I scroll through the code, I am looking for an easy way for when I find something suspicious to isolate the individual change where this line was added.   Currently I use a second window with a 'git blame' and just follow along.  when I see something interesting I spawn a new diff from git blame.

Is there a better way to do with without jumping all over the place?  I am using tortoisegit with winmerge to make the display a bit nicer but not married to any of these tools

Answer (score 1):

Use the power of web git repositories such as [github](https://github.com/), [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/), or [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/).  They offer interesting GUIs for looking at pull requests, diffs, etc.

- Github: open source oriented, pay for private repos
- Gitlab: private is possible, even for free
- Bitbucket: private is possible, even for free

Also:

- Gitlab can be installed locally so you can be totally isolated, too (100% free/open-source community edition, plus an enterprise edition if support is a mandated requirement).
- [addendum] Bitbucket also does this, using a freeware/freemium model (presently: free up to 5 users).

Comment: The "Also" applies to Bitbucket too.

Comment: I will have to check some of these choices.  I need to keep my code in the company supported repositories.   We mostly use git w/phabricator but we have started to use github also.   we have jira and other atlassian products so we might have bitbucket too...  So I guess I have at least bitbucket and gitlab and github to check out